# How can I identify unique conversions?

Tags: google-analytics

You guys can help me with one question?

How can I identify unique conversions? How can I get a ID from each conversion or set an ID to each conversion?

This is, for example, have a direct link between a conversion and a row in my data table. To identify a conversion to a checkout, etc. To the conversion have more info besides being only a number.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got some answers at Google Analytics G+ group: https://plus.google.com/106406414576528220235/posts/BzyeHDLr5to